# update listview in a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

i have an activity with three fragments, i need to update listview in 3rd fragment from 2nd, but it gives me null pointer exception,

from second fragment, i have a button, and its onclick, i do like,

```
Fragment3 fragment3 =  new Fragment3();
fragment3.reload(fragment3.getActivity());
```

and then on the other side(fragment3), i am using,

```
public void reload(Activity activity) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    thisContext = activity;
    mList = getdata();

    if(mList !=null && mList.size() > 0 ) {
        if(listAdapter !=null){
            listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        } else {
            listAdapter = new CustomListAdapter(thisContext, mList);
            setListAdapter(listAdapter);
        }
    }
}
```

when i debug, my context is null, please help!

Answer (score 1):

To expand on Ascorbin's answer, you are creating a **new** instance of Fragment3 which is not associated with your current Activity.

The approach to communicating with other Fragments is documented [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html).

In short, you should be letting your Activity *obtain an existing instance* of Fragment3 and call the `reload` method of that Fragment.

Answer (score 0):

When you create your new Fragment with

```
Fragment3 fragment3 =  new Fragment3();
```

it isn't attached to the Activity yet, so

`fragment3.getActivity()`

will be null.

Assuming you do the first part of your code in an Activity, do

```
Fragment3 fragment3 =  new Fragment3();
fragment3.reload(getApplicationContext());
```

Better yet imho would be if you didn't create a new fragment but use an old instance of fragment3 and just update the existing `ListView`.

Comment: Fragment3 fragment3 = (Fragment3) MainActivity.mAdapter.getItem(2);
       

fragment3 .reload(getActivity());
this does nothing, exception is not more ther

Comment: I'm pretty sure the getItem() method of your Adapter will also create a new Fragment. Inform yourself on how to keep reference to your old fragments or do your initial thing with the new fragment.